# Running ROS as a root user

Tags: ros, root, rosrun, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

Some of my ROS nodes need to be run as a root user. I can do this by "sudo su" under Ubuntu and "source" setup.bash. My programs seem to be running correctly. An annoying issue is that, when I try to use "tab completion" to complete the package name in the terminal (e.g., rosrun package_name executable_name), I got some warnings as follows:

```
[rospack] WARNING: cannot create rospack cache directory: Permission denied
[rospack] WARNING: cannot create rospack cache directory: Permission denied
[rospack] Unable to create temporary cache file /root/.ros/.rospack_cache.bGXJPX: Permission denied
```

I have done this: `chmod -R a+rwx /root/.ros/`, but above warnings still come out.

Any suggestion for solving this problem is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11300/running-ros-as-a-root-user/) by [HZ](https://answers.ros.org/users/1054/hz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2011-09-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rado0x54](https://answers.ros.org/users/708/rado0x54/) on 2011-09-28**:
As joq said already, I cannot think of any circumstance where root permissions are the absolute solution. Tell us why you "need to run as root" and we can probably help you figure it out.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-09-24**:
If possible, a better solution would be to figure out how to set permissions so ROS nodes need not run as root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could add the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH to the root user's .bashrc. In Ubuntu, this is taboo, but in systems where you act as the root user often, it could be helpful.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2011-11-26**:
Setting ROS_HOME to my usual users .ros helped somewhat, however now rospack still complains about directories it cant read. Something in rospack or the tab completion stuff is run with non-root privileges, even though i start it from root. It does not really make sense to me.

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2011-11-21**:
Did you add your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH to the root user's .bashrc? Additionally, you can set your ROS_HOME variable to point to your username's directories. I have my root user's ROS_HOME set to /home/me/.ros instead of /home/root/.ros

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2011-11-20**:
I don't understand how this answers the question? I'm having the same problem and not having tab completion is very annoying. Please don't tell me I should not run as root, I'm perfectly aware of what I'm doing.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-11-16**:
As @joq commented above it's recommended not to run as root in general and to provide specific processes access to resources if necessary.